# Why is the set of all linear transformations $L$ between two vector spaces infinite-dimensional?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

That is, the set of $L : V \rightarrow W$ from a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ to an infinite-dimensional vector space $W$.

Comment: The case where $V$ has dimension $1$ should give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a first course on linear algebra, you usually learn that $L(\Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^m)\cong M_{n\times m}(\Bbb R)$ as vector spaces. (That last thing denotes $n\times m$ matrices over $\Bbb R$.) In this case, the set is clearly finite dimensional.

But if your second space is infinite dimensional, can you see it will contain a copy of $L(\Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^m)$ for each $m$. You can draw your conclusion this way.

Alternatively, you can prove that the transformations can still be represented by "infinitely long" matrices. The proof is not substantially different from the finite case. If $W$ has dimension $\kappa$, and $V$ is $n$ dimensional, then you can show (using the same reasoning as in the finite dimensional cases) that $L(V,W)$ is isomorphic to the set of matrices with $n$ rows and columns indexed by $\kappa$ *which have finitely many nonzero entries in each row.*

(And of course, if you are working over any other field, the result is the same.)

Comment: Regarding your alternative proof, I think I might've read somewhere that a matrix representation of $L$ only applies to mappings between finite-dimensional subspaces, so wouldn't it not be valid to show an "infinitely long" matrix? (I might be wrong)

Comment: Dear @ujx : If $W$ has dimension $\kappa$, and $V$ is $n$ dimensional, then you can show (using the same reasoning as in the finite dimensional cases) that $L(V,W)$ is isomorphic to the set of matrices with $n$ rows and columns indexed by $\kappa$ *which have finitely many nonzero entries in each row.*