# Proving that the set of linear maps from $F^n$ to $P(F)$ is infinite dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Show that $\mathcal{L}(F^n, P(F))$ is infinite dimensional. 
$F$ is any field, and $P(F)$ is the set of polynomials with coefficients in $F$.

I keep thinking that by showing that $P(F)$ is infinite dimensional, we can somehow show that $\mathcal{L}$ is infinite dimensional, but at the same time, that seems not quite right.

Comment: What's $F$? Any field? What's $P(F)$? Polynomials with coefficients in $F$?

Comment: $F$ is any field, and $P(F)$ is the set of polynomials with coefficients in $F$ yes, apologies for being unclear.

Comment: I've spent a fair amount of time looking at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437804/why-is-the-set-of-all-linear-transformations-l-between-two-vector-spaces-infin) but it doesn't quite make sense to me.

Comment: In general, the statement is false. However, if you restrict to the case $n>0$, ...

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that $P(F)$ means $F[X]$. If so, let $(e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n)$ be the canonical basis of $F^n$. For each $N\in\mathbb N$, let $\varphi_N\colon F^n\longrightarrow F[X]$ be the linear map such that $\varphi_N(e)=X^N$ and that $\varphi_N(e_k)=0$ if $k\in\{2,3,\ldots,n\}$. The the $\varphi_N$'s are linearly independente and therefore $\mathcal{L}\bigl(F^n,F[X]\bigr)$ is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: Hm, I'm still a bit confused here. I'm not quite sure that $F[X]$ means, because I'm not familiar with the notation, but I'll assume we're talking about the set of polynomials with coefficients in $F$. 

By canonical basis, I'm assuming that the standard basis is valid? or what exactly does that mean in this context?

I'm also struggling to understand the jump, between the $φ_N$ and linear independence.

Comment: $F[X]$ is the set of polynomials in one variable ($X$) with coefficients in $F$ and, yes, I should have written standard basis. What jump are you talking about?

Comment: I'm getting a little lost at "such that $φ_N(e)=X^N$." I don't quite understand what this notation means. You've said it is the set of polynomials in one variable $X$ with coefficients in $F$, but if we're looking at the set of all polynomials, I don't quite get it, nor what comes after that.

Comment: @user460702 You don't know what $X^N$ means?

Comment: I think I just got confused because it was capitalized. My mistake.